# MongoDb , Node js , express Подключения

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

Можно ли подключится на Mongo Db с node JS Если да Можете дать сылку на статю , просто у нас блокирован сайт , мне хочется взоимодействовать с установочным mongoDb

Comment: [MERN](https://www.mongodb.com/mern-stack)

Comment: Используем модуль `mongojs` - https://github.com/mongo-js/mongojs